# swig: 3.0.12 -> 4.0.2 migration: .so import

Tags: python-3.x, python-import, swig

I am migrating a python2+swig-3.0.12 codebase to python3+swig-4.0.2 .

The directory layout is:

```
base_dir/_xxx.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
base_dir/xxx/__init__.py
base_dir/xxx/xxx.py
```

The PYTHONPATH is pointing to base-dir. The import of _xxx.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so fails because it is restricted to the local directory by this generated code fragment.

```
# Import the low-level C/C++ module                                                                                                                                                                                                           
if __package__ or "." in __name__:
    from . import _xxx
else:
    import _xxx
```

If I use plain 'import _xxx' in both cases the import will succeed. I really do not want to change the  directory layout, is there a way around this problem?

Comment: I have a brute force solution - added option to emit code that is not checking for __package__ and dot. I am not sure it is the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided by swig team on github: https://github.com/swig/swig/issues/2260#issuecomment-1100915731

The solution is in interface file customization, use

```
%module(package="mypackage", moduleimport="import $module") foo
vs
%module(package="mypackage") foo
```